# Fetching data from one sheet, to produce organised summary and display it in sections

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying generate a summary page for a list of lessons from a different sheet.

I'm currently using the formula `=UNIQUE(FILTER('Lessons NEW'!$E2:$E1009,(RIGHT(LEFT('Lessons NEW'!$E2:$E1009,5),1)="1")+(LEN('Lessons NEW'!$E2:$E1009)=3)))` to do so.

This is displaying my list like so, with the code column being the only really important one, as the rest could be fetched from it's result.

[image: example of current result]

This works, but there are two features that I want working that I've not been able to find a way to do;

1. Split the output into groups. I am after a title to each group/section, and a gap between them too. As in screenshot here.

   [image: demo of outputting into sections]
2. Arrange it to display in multiple columns (As in have half the results in column B, and half in column G for example.) In the process of this, I'd prefer the resulting sections (as in point 1, aren't broken, and kept together instead of being split between columns.

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is too much, or very much doable, but keen for suggestions or ideas if there is a way.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've updated the formula (above) and added a title to the source column that it's fetching from. It's now producing this.

[image]

What I want it to do, is to break it further for aesthetics and for easy separation when others are looking at it, and to bolden the title row for each section. (I think I can work out the conditional formatting for the title row...)
This is what I want it to end up looking like.

[image]

Google drive link to demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yx9LWeV7RHfmlldUpdUZjaU8eVdOsUVaeFrfoBypeDs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You've tagged `excel` only, not `Google Sheets`, yet your current formula applies only to the latter. Can you clarify?

Comment: Right you are, I didn't realised that and thought it was for both. I started this on Excel only, but was doing some work using google sheets, as several people were performing tasks on the one file at once. Ideally I would like this to work on both, and I was sure I'd used this lookup formula before in a different spot without issues.

Comment: Added more info, and google drive link to demo sheet. Thanks.